# RSync for SSH in windows powershell

Tags: powershell, ssh, rsync

I recently learned that you could use ssh directly from Windows Powershell: https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Use-SSH-Client-and-Server-on-Windows-10-1470/

I am trying to manage a cluster to do simulations from my windows computer. I can properly use ssh in powershell, but rsync is not recognised.
I found solution online that require the use of Cygwin or cwRync, but is there any way to directly "install" it to be compatible with native power shell?

PS: I am very new to everything related to SSH or Linux and mostly coded on windows through IDEs, sorry if my question is irrelevent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, not at this time, no.

The powershell team stated in 2018 that they consider supportng rsync to be out of scope, and closed the github issue requesting support accordingly: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1266